# How to add elements from one dictionary into other? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have main dictionary.

```
mainDict = {'count': 10, 'a': {'abc': {'additional': 0, 'missing': 0, 'changed': 0}}}
```

Now i have new dictionary with same keys as in mainDict, called this dictionary as `b` with different values.

```
b = {'count': 20, 'a': {'abc': {'additional': 10, 'missing': 10, 'changed': 10}}}
```

I want to update(addition operation) the values of keys in main dictionary so i do..

```
mainDict = {'count': mainDict['count'] + b['count'], 'a': }
```

I am stuck at updating values of `key a`. If i use mainDict.update(b) then it will replace previous values. Any efficient solution??

The final output required is:

```
mainDict = {'count': 30, 'a': {'abc': {'additional': 10, 'missing': 10, 'changed': 10}}}
```

Thanks

Comment: So `b` has the same **structure** as `mainDict`, and you want to match up values recursively and sum them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def recursive_dict_sum_helper(v1, v2):
    # "add" two values: if they can be added with '+', then do so,
    # otherwise expect dictionaries and treat them appropriately.
    try: return v1 + v2
    except: return recursive_dict_sum(v1, v2)

def recursive_dict_sum(d1, d2):
    # Recursively produce the new key-value pair for each
    # original key-value pair, and make a dict with the results.
    return dict(
        (k, recursive_dict_sum_helper(v, d2[k]))
        for (k, v) in d1.items()
    )

mainDict = recursive_dict_sum(mainDict, b)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works very well :) I wish i could be a master in Python like you :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd write:

```
def sum_dicts_recursive(d1, d2):
    for k, v1 in d1.items():
        if isinstance(v1, dict):
            yield (k, dict(process(v1, d2[k])))
        else:
            yield (k, v1 + d2[k])

result = dict(sum_dicts_recursive(mainDict, b))
# {'count': 30, 'a': {'abc': {'changed': 10, 'additional': 10, 'missing': 10}}}
```

Note that `sum_dicts_recursive` can be writter as a one-liner generator expression, but that'd probably be harder to understand.